# Sign PDF with signature hash provided by api

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, sign, pkcs#7

I am trying to sign a pdf with `PDFBox` and a third-party signature provider.

#### My procedure:

1. Getting the pdf from user input
2. Creating a PDDocument with the content of the given pdf
3. creating a PDSignature with all given properties such as organisation or location but without the signature-hash itself.
4. adding this signature object to the PDDocument and creating a digest from the PDDocument to send to the API.
5. Awaiting a successful answer from the API (containing the signature hash) and inserting this hash into the PDDocuments PDSignature object without altering the whole document.

#### My problem:

I can create the PDDocument, the PDSignature and the digest of it and send it to the API. I then get the correct and valid signature hash back from the API and I can add it to the PDDocument but whenever this works, the resulting pdf has an invalid signature due to "being altered or manipulated"(the signer, timestamp and certificate are valid). I also tried to use the `ExternalSigningSupport` from `PDFBox` but I cannot use it as I always run into an error:

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: signature reserve byte range has been changed after addSignature(), please set the byte range that existed after addSignature()".
```

#### My Code that works but invalidates the signature:

```
//Pending Signature is just a DTO
public static PendingSignature createPendingSignatureFromPdf(InputStream pdf2sign, OutputStream fos, String sigName, String sigLocation, String sigReason, String contactInfo, Date forcedDate, Long revisionId) throws IOException {
    
        File pdfFileToSigned = createTempFile("chars", "" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        File pdfPreparedToBeSigned = createTempFile("chars", "" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        File pdfHashPreparedToBeSigned = createTempFile("chars", "" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    
        try {
            if (fos == null) {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfPreparedToBeSigned);
            }
    
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(pdf2sign, pdfFileToSigned);
    
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFileToSigned);
            PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
    
            signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
            signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
    
            if (contactInfo != null && !contactInfo.isEmpty()) {
                signature.setContactInfo(contactInfo);
            }
            if (sigLocation != null && !sigLocation.isEmpty()) {
                signature.setLocation(sigLocation);
            }
            if (sigReason != null && !sigReason.isEmpty()) {
                signature.setReason(sigReason);
            }
            if (sigName != null && !sigName.isEmpty()) {
                signature.setName(sigName);
            }
            if (forcedDate != null) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(sdf.parse(sdf.format(forcedDate)));
                signature.setSignDate(cal);
            }
    
            final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfHashPreparedToBeSigned);
            SignatureInterface signatureInterface = new SignatureInterface() {
                @Override
                public byte[] sign(InputStream content) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                        byte[] imp = digest.digest(content.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
                        IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(imp), outputStream);
                        return new byte[0];
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return new byte[0];
                    }
                }
            };
    
            SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
            signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(SignatureOptions.DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_SIZE * 8);
    
            doc.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface, signatureOptions);
    
            if (revisionId != null) {
                doc.setDocumentId(revisionId);
            } else {
                doc.setDocumentId(0L);
            }
            doc.saveIncremental(fos);
    
            PendingSignature pendingSignature = new PendingSignature(doc, signature, IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(pdfHashPreparedToBeSigned)));
            return pendingSignature;
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        } finally {
            fos.close();
            pdf2sign.close();
            FileUtils.deleteQuietly(pdfFileToSigned);
            FileUtils.deleteQuietly(pdfPreparedToBeSigned);
            FileUtils.deleteQuietly(pdfHashPreparedToBeSigned);
        }
     }
    
    //Gets called when the api returns sucess with the signedbytes
    public static File insertHashToPdf(PendingSignature pendingSignature, final byte[] signedBytes) throws IOException {
    
        File outputDocument = createTempFile("chars", "" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputDocument);
    
        PDDocument doc = pendingSignature.getPdfDocument();
        PDSignature pdfSignature = pendingSignature.getPdfSignature();
    
        //Produces signature that it invalid because it was altered or manipulated
        pdfSignature.setContents(signedBytes);
    
        doc.saveIncremental(fos);
    
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    
        return outputDocument;
    }
```

Signature looks like that:

[image: InvalidSignature]

Does anybody know how to insert this signature hash into the whole PDDocument without invalidating it?

Comment: As signing with PDFBox does work (using the PDFBox examples, using its integration in eSig DSS, etc.), there likely is an issue in your code. Thus, you probably should share your pivotal code and an example PDF signed with it.

Comment: Hi POP3 -> you need to add your source code to the question, otherwise it is anyone's guess

Comment: I tried to include all the code that could be helpful now.

Comment: Your `sign()` method only produces a digest, not a signature. You seem to be confusing signing with digesting. I don't know what exactly you mean by a 'signature hash', but whatever you sign, you can't change the content of afterwards.

Comment: The error is not quite as simple as @user207421 assumes, POP3 in `insertHashToPdf` tries to inject an actual signature container; if it was a mere hash, the Adobe Reader could not have determined an identity of the signer, let alone one it trusts. I think the issue is that the signing base classes here are not made for calling `saveIncremental` twice, at least not with a `PDSignature` callback and a change in its content value. POP3, is it not possible to simply retrieve and return the signature inside your `SignatureInterface.sign` implementation?

Comment: @user207421 my sign() method (i assume you mean "createPendingSignatureFromPdf()") only creates a digest from the PDDocument thats correct but that is all that i need from it. I get my signature from an api which needs that digest to create the signature hash which i then later inject into the PDDocument.

Comment: @mkl thanks for your question. The problem is that the signature-api awaits a two factor authentication and i need to make additional calls in order to retrieve the signature. Also i need to create the signature and add it to the PDDocument before sending it to the api for the api expects a signature to be present in the document-digest. That makes sense as when i would add the signature after creating the signed hash i would alter the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally found a working solution.

Link to day saving repo: https://github.com/crs2195/signature/tree/master/RemoteSignature-%20PDFBox/CSC-PDFBox

Comment: Did you need the whole repo or just the sign() implementation? If the later, then it would be more useful if you copy that implementation here.

Comment: I used the whole CSCSignature.java class but with some changes as i could not use the filesystem but had to make it in memory.